# How to get max value + other column using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

This is my query:

```
$maxvalue= market::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->max('price');
```

But in addition to the `max` value I also want to get the `user_id` column. How would I do that?

Comment: Could you provide more information about how `Market` y `User` are related? there's a `user_id` in the `markets` table or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `max()` Eloquent function, but you can use MySQL's `max()` function with `DB::raw()`. You'll need to use groupBy as well so you can get it per user:

```
$maxValues = market::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
                 ->groupBy('user_id')
                 ->get(['user_id', DB::raw('max(price) as max_price'));
```